# Why am I getting an error when trying to run a new react native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a new react native project by running "react-native init MyFirstProject". I have also installed node and have added no code of my own to any of the files.

I have tried to run the project to make sure it works by running "react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"". The command runs successfully but I am given the following error.

> Could not connect to development server.
>
> Ensure the following:
>
> - Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
> - Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
> - WiFi is enabled and connected to the same network as the Node Server
>
> URL: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false
>
> RCTFatal
>   __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
>
> _dispatch_call_block_and_release
>
> _dispatch_client_callout
>
> _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
>
> **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
>
> __CFRunLoopRun
>
> CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   Blockquote
>   GSEventRunModal
>
> UIApplicationMain
>
> main
>
> start

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Do you have virtual device up running? or You do you have actual device connected to your computer?

Comment: virtual device with Xcode

Comment: Would retry building the server again?

Comment: I have done that and seem to be still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your project `ios/MyFirstProject/MyFirstProject.xcworkspace` and see if there's any build error.

Comment: I did this and fixed the build errors but am still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, with the same error:

```
RCTFatal __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
```

It turned out that I had another server running on my local machine on the same port that the expo development client server was running (`:8081`), and that it was taking priority and then obviously giving the client a very different response to what it was expecting. Quitting the other server fixed the problem.